# example in Rudin in maximum modulus situation

Tags: real-analysis

Section 5.22 of Rudin says,
"Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space, let $H$ be a compact subset of $K$, and let $A$ be a subspace of $C(K)$ such that $1\in A$ and such that $\|f\|_K=\|f\|_H$ for $f\in A.$ Here we used the notation $\|f\|_E=\sup\{|f(x)|:x\in E\}$."

It seems to me that two continuous functions can achieve their maximum magnitude on a subset $H$ but their sum does not. So how is $A$ a subspace?

Comment: Are you sure that the subspace is defined by this property, or is it a subspace that, additionally, satisfies this property ?

Comment: @charMD It is the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps what that passage could have been written more clearly, but I will say what I think may have been intended.

First a simple example: Suppose $K=\{1,2,3\}$ with the discrete topology and $H=\{2,3\}.$

The functions $\begin{array}{l} 1\mapsto 2 \\ 2 \mapsto 3 \\ 3\mapsto 0 \end{array}$ and $\begin{array}{l} 1\mapsto 2 \\ 2 \mapsto 0 \\ 3\mapsto 3 \end{array}$ both attain their maximum value within $H,$ but their sum attains its maximum elsewhere.

But notice that it did not say "Let $A$ be **the** subspace consisting of functions attaining their maxima in $H,$ but rather, let $A$ be **a** subspace consisting of functions attaining their maxima in $H.$ In other words, $A$ is not intended to contain **all** such functions; rather $A$ contains some such functions and $A$ is closed under linear combination.

Comment: Actually Rudin is very clear in writing it the way he did, although if English is not your first language it might seem confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Rudin is just saying **suppose** $A$ has that property. Example: $A$ could be the linear subspace of $C(\overline{\mathbb D})$ consisting of those functions in $C(\overline{\mathbb D})$ that are harmonic in $\mathbb D.$ In fact, that is exactly what he has in mind in this section called "An abstract approach to the Poisson kernel".